# ORA 01034 and ORA 27101- ORACLE Error

Tags: database, oracle11g

I'm using CentOS 7. My ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_XE is properly set. Yet when I try to configure my oracle 11g, I get the following error:

```
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
LRM-00116: syntax error at 'sessions' following '='
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
```

I'm configuring using /etc/init.d/oracle-xe command.

Please help.

```
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
ORACLE_SID= XE
```

Comment: Looks like the database isn't running. How are you trying to configure it - do you have a database you're trying to modify, or are you trying to create a new database? Exactly what commands are you running to get those messages, and from where?

Answer (score 1):

Below are the steps we should take to ensure the correct installation and Configuration of Oracle XE on CentOS 7

1. Install libaio1, bc (yum install libaio1 and yum install bc)
2. Allocate a proper swap space
3. Set ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID
4. Check is your IP and hostname is present in /etc/hosts file.

Other than this, https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/oracle-db-11gr2-installation-on-oracle-linux-7 gives a good checklist but the above 4 **MUST** be done. 
I was facing this issue because Bouncy Castle was not installed